# I want to add a variable in python script from different python3 script which will act as a global variable or one point of access of that variable

Tags: python

example:-

**file1.py**

```
v=10
name="lko"
```

**file2.py**

```
import file1
print(file1.v)
file1.add(surname="dhg")
```

*And I want that this surname variable to be reflected in file1.py*
*i.e*

**file1.py**

```
v=10
name="lko"
surname="dhg"
```

Comment: `file1.surname = "dhg"`? But you really shouldn't rely on global mutable state

Comment: But this statement could not able to add "surname" in "file1.py"

Comment: you mean *as source code*? Why would you want to do that? That is generally not how things work. You likely want to use some sort of serialization or even just a config file (maybe even simply JSON). In any case, the module object itself doesn't really care about the actual file it was loaded from, although it has that knowledge, there is no built-in way to modify the file, and honestly, it sounds highly inadvisable.